# Servlet cannot get absolute path of a properties file

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

Kinda wondering why this happens.
Same code but different result.

```
File file = new File("src/config/ora2.config.properties");
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

In a regular java class, it results right path but when in servlet, it returns the installation path of eclipse.

Thanks in advance

**EDITED**

```
Properties props = new Properties();
InputStream in = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("WEB-INF/ora2.config.properties");
if(in != null) {
      try {
        props.load(in);

        props.setProperty("username", "temtem");

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(in.toString());
        props.store(out, null);
        out.close();
    } finally {
    in.close();
    }
```

Code above is not working :(

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. It shows that you're running this class from Eclipse?

Comment: Yes. Im running this at eclipse. Does it affect? How can I attain the right absolute path running in servlet?

Answer (score 0):

`new File(...)` treats the path as relative to the current working directory of the java process, whatever that happens to be. If you're building a servlet for eventual deployment on a standalone server system then you can't necessarily depend on this being a sensible location. Instead you should put this kind of configuration file somewhere under your application's `WEB-INF` and use the `getResource` or `getResourceAsStream` methods of the `ServletContext` to access it, which resolve relative paths against the location of this specific web application.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
InputStream in = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/ora2.config.properties");
if(in != null) {
  try {
    props.load(in);
  } finally {
    in.close();
  }
}
```

If you absolutely must access the properties as a `java.io.File` rather than a URL or input stream (e.g. if you have to pass the path to third party code that can't accept a stream or a `Properties` object directly) then ServletContext also has a. `getRealPath` method you can use, but that requires that the web application be expanded as a real directory on disk, it won't work if you're running directly from a WAR file. The `getResource` methods don't have this restriction.

Comment: Can you give exactly the code I will run from a servlet whereas my properties file will reside under WEB-INF

Comment: Can that code also save the modified variables on the properties file?

Comment: @user3264438 in a server environment you can't necessarily assume you have permission to write files inside the web application, or indeed anywhere else apart from the temporary directory provided in `getServletContext().getAttribute(ServletContext.TEMPDIR)` (which may not persist across restarts). If you need a persistent config file then you'd be better passing its full path to the servlet as an init parameter, or changing your architecture to store data in a database instead of files.

Comment: That file contains the database parameter e.g. username, password, driverclass, url. Feature is to change the parameters then connect to another database. I am developing a code that can load, modify and save a properties file. I can load smoothly the file but when I save it, error occurs. Either null or system cannot find the file. I have placed the file under WEB-INF as you said.

Comment: @user3264438 with respect, that seems like a rather odd design - I'd normally expect the database settings to be something that has to be configured by the administrator when they deploy a web application, rather than something that can be modified directly through the app.  But if you do need read-write access to a persistent config file then the only sure way to do it is to supply the absolute path to the file as a parameter to the application (e.g. as a `context-param` in `web.xml`, which can be overridden by the admin for production deployment).